# How to broadcast a folder in network of class B network?

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring

I want my specific folder on every pc which is in common network of my college 

so how to broadcast that folder is there any command like ssh? 

please help me fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept about broadcasting a folder!! What you can do instead is 
making a directory shared to others without permissions, so that every one in your network can see, read and write in it.

Install Samba

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Set a password for your user in Samba

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <user_name>
```

Create a directory to be shared

```
mkdir /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
```

Edit the file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Once "smb.conf" has loaded, add this to the very end of the file:

```
[<folder_name>]
path = /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
available = yes
valid users = <user_name>
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Restart the samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Now every one in your network can find this shared directory

Comment: Its ok but the network is available only for today and i want that folder in every pc 
I can zip it and make it as a file so is there any way to share that zip file 
I know scp can do it but don't know how to broadcast it 
scp -r filename root@ip:/path_of_file /where_to_save_location this works but there are many pc and i cant do this with every ip

Comment: No the network will be forever and for every pc in your network

Comment: so no alternative to do it?